# How to find out where root Anaconda/Miniconda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

Assume I installed Anaconda/Miniconda (with conda 4.5.*) but didn't add it to PATH. Then I created environment in non-standard location (not in `./envs/`). Now everything I know is the path to python exec in this environment. How can I activate it? Should I find out where original root Miniconda is installed? How? Is there any way I can figure out that it's a conda created environment (so that it differs from other python)?

And I need methods that solve this problem both on Windows and on Linux. Actually I need to generate wrapper that activates conda env/virtual env (or don't activate if it's not an env) from setup.py post-install script that is pip installed from source (not wheel). I already know that if on Windows when pip is run it prepends `<pyhon_env>\Library\bin` to PATH (maybe if it's not already there), but it's not enough (or I don't know how to use it).

Answer (score 0):

When run Conda sets `CONDA_ROOT` environment variable that contains absolute path to the root of the Anaconda/Miniconda installation (even if you didn't add it to PATH).

So you can get access to `CONDA_ROOT` when setup.py is run (during creation of env from yaml that has pip deps) and store it somewhere. I still don't know how to find conda root when installation is finished and you activate env and pip install...